# has mongodb object size any effect on reading performance on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, disk, querying, sector

my question is about improving query performance on mongodb. In storage disk, a sector is 512 bytes. And disk head reads data from disk sector by sector.

Let's assume that if average Object size of MongoDB document is 100 byte, each sector will include about 5 documents and disk head will fetch 5 documents on each read. If average object size is 300 byte, disk head will fetch 1 documents on each read.

I think that this situation will effects MongoDB query performance. First example works 5x times faster. Am I wrong?

If my idea is right, should I consider this situation while designing my MongoDB database?

If I make mistake, what's the wrong thing about this idea?

Comment: Well the short answer is "of course it does", however it naturally needs to be a lot more long winded than that. You also seem to be ignoring the basic principle that a "database" just like any optimized program for it's purpose will prefer to use RAM  or indeed the memory access with the least delay in recalling the data, so it's not all about "disk storage" or "sectors". It also is not really a "programming question" as suited for this site. [dba.stackexhange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) might be a better choice. But even for there I would be thinking this is a broad topic.

Comment: I might add, that there is a "subtext" here about "how big should my objects be for my app performance" that I do see. But the possible variations on explaining all of that gets pretty large. You could "tune" this to be more specific to a case you really have. But the general breakdown I see immediately is "just recal the fields you need" when you need to interact with the data stored in an object.

Comment: @BlakesSeven , as you say, memory usage is more important for a database because of their nature. In addition, I'm working on a slow PC and I'm testing something for my app. I'm trying to make queries faster. For this topic, I had been confused bur with your answers, I have no doubt about this topic. I consider your answer for my application. Thanks a lot.